# What does the <rd:Selected> do exactly?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, rdl

Accidentally removed this line

```
<rd:Selected>true</rd:Selected>
```

not sure what it actually does, if it's worth going through and recovering it.

Tried Googling and looking up documentation and couldn't seem to find anything defining what it does

Answer (score 0):

From my research it appears the rd tag is used to hold design time values, so I don’t believe it effects the rendering.